# SQL filter to replace duplicate value records with one single custom value record

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace, duplicates

I am trying to create a report that shows a count of items (store_Product) purchased by store location(store_ID).

My issue is that when a distinct store location purchases both product_a and product_b, then I need the report to show one record of that store_ID with store_Product as "product_A" instead of having two records with same store_ID and both product_A and product_B. 
However, if a distinct store location only purchases product_A OR product_B (but not both) then it would show one record of that store_ID along with what product it purchased as it normally does now.

On the left is what I am getting right now and on the right is what I want the result to look like:

[image]

How can I achieve this result?

Thanks!

Comment: ah? Can you please give us output expected result?

Comment: @Dalorzo I have added an expected output image on the main post.

Comment: @KashifQureshi All i have right now is just the basic select statement and filters. I am not sure how to even go in the right direction with this.

Comment: Do you have a products table, and is it in the order you want your products to override each other? I.e. if product_A is before product_B in the table then product_A will be the one reported if both are present?

Comment: what database server are you using?

Comment: Does it matter which product is chosen to display in the case of there being multiple?

Comment: when there are duplicates of store_ID (no matter which order the product_ID is in), I would like the product_ID to be changed to 'product_A'

Comment: @KashifQureshi i am using MS SQL server 2014

Comment: @AaronDietz I would always want it to select product_A every single time, no matter what order its in.

Answer (score 1):

In Microsoft SQL Server, you can achieve this by using `CTE`:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (
  store_id int,
  store_product varchar(25)
)

INSERT INTO #temp
  VALUES (100, 'product_A')
  , (100, 'product_B')
  , (200, 'product_B')
  , (300, 'product_A')
  , (400, 'product_B')
  , (400, 'product_A')


;WITH cte
AS (SELECT
  *,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY store_id ORDER BY store_id, store_product) AS rn
FROM #temp)
SELECT
  store_id , store_product 
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1

DROP TABLE #temp
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! So this is my fault but I forgot to mention that there are store_product values other than product_A and product_B.

This query is changing the other store_products (such as product_C) into product_A also when there are duplicate store_ID.

I only need the duplicate store_ID to be replaced with single record IF both duplicates are "product_A" and "product_B"

If there are duplicate store_ID with lets say "product_A" and "product_D" then I would like both records to show up. Sorry for the confusion, hope you can help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
select store_id, min(store_product) as store_product
from table_name
group by store_id;
```

... its another dirty trick that will work with the sample data ;)

Answer (score 0):

In a comment to an answer you are correcting your request. You want to suppress product_B when the same store also has product_A. All other rows shall remain in the result. At least this is how I understand this now.

One way to achieve this is with a `NOT IN` (or `NOT EXISTS`) clause:

```
select
  store_id,
  store_product
from mytable
where store_product <> 'product_B'
   or store_id not in (select store_id from mytable where store_product = 'product_A');
```

or if you find that more readable:

```
select
  store_id,
  store_product
from mytable
where not
(
  store_product = 'product_B' and
  store_id in (select store_id from mytable where store_product = 'product_A')
);
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I want to replace, not suppress, product_B with product_A when the same store_ID also has product_A. I believe your method would just remove product_B from a counting perspective whereas replacing with product_A, the count would remain the same, just now changed to product_A category. 

No changes would be made if:

a store has ONLY (one of) product_B OR product_A OR product_C;

OR when a store has both product_C AND product_A;

OR when a store has product_C AND product_B;

When a store has product_A AND product_B, only then, product_B replace with product_A

Comment: The queries list all stores and products. There is no counting. When a store has both product_A and product_B, product_B is not shown. That seems to match what you are looking for. The only situation that you didn't mention yet is when a store has product_A and product_B and product_C. I would show product_A and product_C, because the store has both product_A and product_B, so only product_A of them gets shown. Is this different from what you want? Have you tried one of the queries? Is the result different from what you are looking for? If so, how?

Comment: Again, I do not want it to be "not shown". Instead, I would want it to show two instances of product_A. So When a store has both product_A and product_B, product_B gets changed to product_A so now that store has two counts of product_A instead of having one product_A and one product_B

Comment: When a store has product_A, product_B AND product_C, then product_B gets replaced with product_A so now that store has two counts of product_A and one count of product_C.

Comment: But this is what my query does. Product_B doesn't get shown, but product_A and product_C yes. I don't see how my query is different from the result you want or from the result you've shown in your request. So again: Have you tried my queries? Are their results different from what you want? If so, in what way different?